# MySQL Nested WHERE - OR

Tags: mysql

I will need a little help here

Problem is - after WHERE clause I only need rows where CBI is Critical or HIGH or there is combination where CBI is Medium and Priority is 1.

Unfortunately I am still getting rows where e.g. CBI is medium and priority is 2

```
SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE (cbi='Critical' OR cbi='High' OR (cbi='Medium' AND priority='1')) 
     AND start_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW() 
      OR involvement_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW() 
      OR finnish_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW();
```

Comment: so whats the problem you raise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem are the or parts between the date selection. There must be brackets arround

```
 SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE (cbi='Critical' OR cbi='High' OR (cbi='Medium' AND priority='1')) 
     AND (start_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW() 
      OR involvement_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW() 
      OR finnish_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND NOW());
```